# Logging in to mysql?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I've set up mysql on ubuntu 16.04.

During set up I created the root users password.

Now I try and log in via terminal (i've ssh'd in to server as the ubuntu user):

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Then I enter my previously set password.

I get:

```
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

Then if I do:

```
sudo su -
```

Then:

```
mysql -u root
```

I'm in, without a password.

What's going on? How can I access it without a password? How can I get the ubuntu user to have access?

Comment: You can access the database without password because the user of your system which you log on to (root) matches with the user name on the database. And it's localhost.

Comment: So there's no chance someone could access it from outside?

Comment: No, of course there is :)

Comment: How can I prevent that then?

Comment: Well, it seems like your comment is a different question than the one we're discussing right now? Look into authentication methods of MySQL. I believe you need to disable plugin authentication for root and reload privileges: `update user set plugin='' where user='root'; flush privileges;`

Comment: There was an error in your sql, should be update mysql.user... anyway this did not work

Comment: As in @Eugene's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40007717/1155833), revoke `root` user privileges to DB, but allow for management of DB server (not DB), using mysql_secure_installation (google it). Create a new user for the specific DB. Run the following command: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `%database_name%`.* TO '%username%'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;`... Also question is more for valid for site [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) (also StackExchange site).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you skipped `mysql_secure_installation`? Try running these, and then check if you're still able to login without a password:

```
DROP USER IF EXISTS ''@'localhost'
DROP USER IF EXISTS ''@'$(hostname)'
```

And regarding security... double check `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`, `iptables`, `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, and pretty much everything actually.